# PHP + PDO: Bind null if param is empty

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, nullable

I'm trying this (and all PoST var are treated before user send it, no SQL Injection worries):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":1", $this->getPes_cdpessoa());
$stmt->bindParam(":2", $this->getPdf_nupessoa_def());
```

When any of those vars are NULL, PDO cries and don't let execute my statement, and on my Table, i DO allow these fields beign nullables.

Is there any way to check if the values are empty, pdo just bind NULL to then (and i mean, a smart way instead if(empty($_POST['blablabla')...) for every single param?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':1', $this->getPes_cdpessoa(), PDO::PARAM_NULL);
$stmt->bindParam(":2", $this->getPdf_nupessoa_def(), PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

Also, see:

- [How do I insert NULL values using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo)

Answer (score 2):

`bindParam` needs an actual variable to be passed to it, because it creates a reference.  So, when your functions return null, bindParam doesn't really have anything valid to do.

You need to use `bindValue` instead.  Note that `bindValue` will immediately use whatever value you pass to it, where `bindParam` waits until statement execution to actually retrieve the values to use.

Comment: if I use bindValue, all the security of Params are gone. All I wanted to do is Allow nulls..

Comment: `bindValue` still gives you the same prepared-statement-and-placeholder goodness that you get with `bindParam`.  The main differences are the time when the value is actually evaluated, and that you can't get DB output like you can with `bindParam`.

Answer (score 0):

The Alternative syntax works:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($this->getPes_cdpessoa(), $this->getPdf_nupessoa_def()));
```