# Binding null to integer column using PDO and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the following code in an attempt to bind NULL to an integer column on a MySQL table:

```
$query->bindValue(1, null, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

However, this causes the value in the column to be "0" instead of NULL.

How can I force the column to be NULL instead of 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I insert NULL values using PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo)

Comment: @Marc - as you can see, I'm using the accepted solution. That solution works for a string column. Not for an integer, which is specifically what I'm asking about.

Comment: you're telling PDO you're passing an INT, so null gets typecast to 0. Try PDO_::PARAM_NULL

Answer (score 3):

```
bindValue(':param', null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```