# PHP mysql PDO refuses to set NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am unable to set a nullable field with a default value of null to null using mysql pdo. I can do it using straight sql.

I have tried: (mostly from this question [How do I insert NULL values using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo))

1. Null Int

   ```
   bindValue(':param', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   ```
2. Null Null

   ```
   bindValue(':param', null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
   ```
3. 'Null', Int

   ```
   bindValue(':param', 'NULL', PDO::PARAM_INT);
   ```
4. 'Null', Null

   ```
   bindValue(':param', 'NULL', PDO::PARAM_NULL);
   ```
5. Null

   ```
   bindValue(':param', null);
   ```
6. 'Null'

   ```
   bindValue(':param', 'NULL');
   ```
7. and the `bindParam` counterparts of 5 and 6 with a variable that held the value of the binding.

**Everything from PDO results in the value being set to 0.**

**PHP Version:** `PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10`

**MYSQL SERVER VERSION:** `5.1.63-0ubuntu0.10.04.1`

**EDIT**
Screenshot of column info

[image: Picture]

Comment: what is the column type? is that nullable?

Comment: @DanielA.White he just said he can do it via straight sql so yes it is nullable.

Comment: can you show us the rest of your code rather than just your bindValue statements?  I suspect if you have tried all these options and it isn't a problem with your actual database then it must be a problem with the rest of your code.

Comment: @Daniel A. White, I've included a screenshot showing the column is nullable plus as Jon Taylor said, I can do this with straight sql.

Comment: @JonTaylor The code that builds the query is half a page long and I am NDA'd from sharing it. I can confirm with no doubts that my value binding call is definitely getting called and is not getting overwritten later on.

Comment: The column has the 'DEFAULT NULL' attribute, did you try setting the columnValue to empty then attempting the execute (save)?

Comment: @hidden_premise not much else we can do to be honest if we cant see any code, have you tried putting in a non null value with the same statement, just to check if it works?

Comment: Since the default is NULL, you can just remove the column entirely from your (I'm assuming) `INSERT/UPDATE` statement and let it handle itself.

Comment: @Palladium wouldnt removing it from the update statement leave it as it was? Rather than making it the default value.

Comment: @JonTaylor RIGHT. Never mind. You can take it out if it's an `INSERT` statement (good catch).

Comment: @Palladium, you can take it out of the statement if it is already NULL, but if you have it already populated with a value and need to NULL it out then the problem remains

Comment: Looks like our villian was me not having prepare emulation set to false `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NULL values do not require any special treatment. Simply bind your value the usual way

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "pass");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `null_test` (`can_be_null`) VALUES (:null)");
$stmt->bindValue(":null", null, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

PDO will detect a null value and send it to database instead of string.

In case of WHERE clause, where your value could be either null or not null, use [Mysql's spaceship operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col <=> :var");
$stmt->bindParam(":var", $nullOrNot);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: This... `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` this little guy right here was the trick. @Truth, Thanks! Great Catch!

Comment: `Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`

Answer (score 2):

I will strong recommend to first assign all parameters to variables and then pass those variables to the `bindParam()` method.

You can assign by passing NULL to those variables and it will work fine.

```
$myVar = NULL;
$conn->bindParam(':param1' , $myVar , PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save an empty string as null, you can use a function like this:

```
function setnull($item){
    if ($item === ""){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        return $item;
    }
}
```

Then you can proceed with insert the usual way.