# php select and json encode issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website to learn PHP and am making an autosuggest from Jquery Ui.

Here's my code ( I took this code from a post on SO a long time ago, and I'm not 100% what it does, so if anyone could explain, it would be helpful!) This code is from suggest.php, which I call to from my jquery code (which I think is working, so I didn't post it, but can If you need it!)

```
<?
include("config.php");

$queryString = strtolower($_GET["q"]);

$return = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM company WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' UNION SELECT cat FROM cat WHERE cat LIKE '$queryString%' UNION SELECT subcat FROM subcat WHERE subcat LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['name'],'value'=>$row['name']));
}
echo(json_encode($return));

?>
```

Right now this is making the autosuggest work, but only with the same results (example, if I type "Johns" it comes up with "Johns Hot Dogs" as a suggestion, but If I type "fjfjdjf669959" then it comes up with "Johns Hot Dogs" as well.

I'm doing a Mysql Union because I'm trying to populate my autosuggest with the **name** row from **company** table, the **cat** row from **cat** table, and the **subcat** row from **subcat** table.

Why is this not working?

Thanks for any and all help!!

My JQUERy code looks like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
            source: "suggest.php"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why "Johns Hot Dogs" comes up with `fjfjf` .. what happens when you run the query manually?  You also need to alias `cat` and `subcat` as `name` if you want them to be added to `return`.

Comment: @Explosion, thanks for the help. Does running the query manually mean going to suggest.php?q= ? If it does then it echoes out  `[["Johns Hot Dogs","Johns Hot Dogs"],` and it repeats for all of my rows in my tables

Comment: well I meant running it with the `mysql` program on the command line, but that way would work too I guess.  It does this even if `q=fjfjfj`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, no if q=fjfjfj, then its just echoes " [] "

Comment: it's possible that the ajax request is cached

Comment: @ExplosionPills, ok so should I post my jquery code?

Comment: You'll be hacked if you publish this code. Google "SQL Injection".

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth, thanks. Definitely will change!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your php code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Furthermore, the [mysql_* functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). Instead, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Your code fails because you're reading the wrong query variable. `$_GET['q']` is empty since the [jQuery UI autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) uses the parameter `term` for the search query. With an empty `$queryString`, you execute the SQL query

```
SELECT name FROM company WHERE name LIKE '%'   -- UNION ...
```

which of course just returns everything. You want:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (!isset($_GET['term'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Missing term parameter in request';
    exit();
}
$queryString = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM company WHERE name LIKE :qs" .
  " UNION SELECT cat AS name FROM cat WHERE cat LIKE :qs" .
  " UNION SELECT subcat AS name FROM subcat WHERE subcat LIKE :qs " .
  " LIMIT 10");
$query->execute(array(':qs' => $queryString . '%'));
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
$result = array_map(function($row) {
    return array('label'=>$row['name'],'value'=>$row['name']);
}, $query->fetchAll());

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo(json_encode($result));
```

[**Here is a live, downloadable (incl. database) demo**](http://phihag.de/2012/so/so-autocomplete/).

Comment: Make sure to set prepared statement emulation to false too.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you can't use the same placeholder name twice in the same prepared statement.

Comment: @Truth What's the problem with prepared statement emulation? And I'm testing it with multiple tables, updating ...

Comment: Setting it to false solves some [edge cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11693505/871050).

Comment: @Truth That looks to be like a workaround for a bug in php or PDO. I think someone may have tested that strings work ;)

Comment: @phihag, thanks for the help. Two questions: 1. When I put in the php code, it gives me an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% UNION SELECT subcat AS name FROM subcat WHERE subcat LIKE '%' LIMIT 10' at line 1' in suggest.php:10 Stack trace: #0 suggest.php(10): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in suggest.php on line 10'`

Comment: and the 2nd question is: Do I have to change name='q' in my searchbox to name='term', or does the jquery do that for me?

Comment: @Jake Sorry, that was an error in the earlier version. I updated the answer, and included a link where you can download a zipfile of a full demo. And the value of the `name` attribute doesn't matter for autocomplete. You are free to set any value.

Comment: @phihag, I'd award you the bounty now, but it wont allow me for 22 hours.