# SELECT from database when i don´t know position of null values

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon. I need your help to make correctly query into database.

I have following table in DB  with adresses, eg.

| id | street | house_nuber | city | district |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First street | 1225 | City One | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | 25 | Small city | NULL |
| 3 | Second street | 51 | Roswell | District nine |
| 4 | Third street | 15963 | Last city | Another district |

In the table above you can see i have adresses. I also have random NULL values in rows. My table has about 50k records for now.

PHP code fill variables with following values

```
$street = 'First street';
$houseNum = 1125;
$city = 'City One';
$district = NULL;
```

I need to return ID from database of matching adress. If i know, where NULL value is, query is easy.

```
SELECT id FROM adress WHERE street=$street AND house_number=$houseNum AND city=$city AND district IS NULL
```

(normaly i use PDO, this is only for ilustration)

And now my question. How to make query, If i can´t predict, where NULL value is?
I tryed to make query with empty strings, but for database is not same the NULL and empty and i always had false return.

Thak you and have a nice day.

Comment: When you have a table with IDs and additional columns of data, queries that specify the ID are generally “lookups” or “retrievals”, whereas queries that specify the other columns are “searches”, which is what you have. When searching, you just throw what you know at the database, and if you don’t know it, you don’t include it. This might mean dynamically building your SQL statement. There’s also the [spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13353424/231316) which might help.

Comment: Hi Chriss Haas, I tryed to aply spaceship operator, but this operator did not solve my problem.  Anyway thank you for your response, I learned something new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match exactly rows in your table, you can use [NULLIF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_nullif) to convert your PHP empty strings to SQL NULL values and [NULL-safe operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) to compare NULL to them without NULL result.

Ex. :

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT id 
    FROM adress 
    WHERE TRUE 
        AND street <=> NULLIF({$pdo->quote($street)}, '')
        AND house_number <=> NULLIF({$pdo->quote($houseNum)}, '')
        AND city <=> NULLIF({$pdo->quote($city)}, '')
        AND district <=> NULLIF({$pdo->quote($city)}, '')
    SQL;
```

Comment: Hi JCH77, thank you for your solution, it works perfectly! I wrote to Chris that the spaceship operator didn't work for me. Apparently, I used it wrong :-). In addition, I learned a very important function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can append the where condition like the below:

```
$street_query = $street != null ? " AND street='$street' " : " AND street IS NULL ";
$houseNum_query = $houseNum != null ? " AND house_number='$houseNum' " : " AND house_number IS NULL ";
$city_query = $city != null ? " AND city='$city' " : " AND city IS NULL ";
$district_query = $district != null ? " AND district='$district' " : " AND district IS NULL ";

$query = "SELECT id FROM adress WHERE 1 = 1 $street_query $houseNum_query $city_query $district_query";
```

***Note:*** `1 = 1` to let next `AND + condition` is always a correct query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is interesting, but it won't completely solve my situation. In any case, it is instructive. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query it finds street, house, etc null or not (match condition)

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM adress WHERE id>0 
AND street = IF($street != null, $street, NULL)
AND house_number = IF($houseNum != null, $houseNum, NULL)
AND city= IF($city != null, $city, NULL) 
AND district= IF($district != null, $district, NULL)
```

---