# Debug PDO mySql insert NULL into database instead of empty

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo, null

I am trying to dynamically insert 'NULL' into the database using PDO.

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Fixes` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'PK',
  `CurrencyId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK',
  `MetalId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK',
  `FixAM` decimal(10,5) NOT NULL,
  `FixPM` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `CurrencyId` (`CurrencyId`),
  KEY `MetalId` (`MetalId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

PHP / PDO QUERY:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE 
            Fixes
    SET 
            FixAM = :fixAM,
        FixPM = :fixPM
        WHERE
            MetalId IN (SELECT Id FROM Metals WHERE Name = :metal) AND
        CurrencyId IN (SELECT Id FROM Currencies Where Id = :currency)';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 

for ($i = 0; $i<3; $i++) {  
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':metal' => 'Silver', 
    ':fixAM' => $fix['FixAM'][$i], 
    ':fixPM' => $fix['FixPM'][$i],
    ':currency' => ($i+1))
    );      
}
```

e.g. sometimes, the value for `$fix['FixPM'][$i]` is **sometimes** 'NULL'. How do I insert this into the database? When I run the query and then view the data in the database, this record shows 0.0000, and not null.

[How do I insert NULL values using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo) provides a few solutions.

- I dont think I can use `$stmt->execute(array( ':v1' => null, ':v2' => ... ))` as per example because sometimes the item is null, and sometimes not. As such, I need to refer to the variable I have created `$fix['FixPM'][$i]` and make that **null** as and when needed

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `FixPM` field nullable in `Fixed` Table schema?

Comment: Hi there, I have clarified the question. Table structure shows that FixPM is nullable.

Comment: Is the variable's value actually `NULL`, or is it the _string_ `'NULL'`, which when cast to a numeric value will cast to `0`?  PDO should handle a real `NULL` correctly, but the string would get cast.

Comment: $fix["FixPM"][0] = null; which doesn't do anything (NO GOOD). and $fix["FixPM"][0] = 'NULL'; which casts to 0.00000 (NO GOOD)

Comment: The actual NULL value doesn't work? I find that strange.  To fix the string you would need something like `':fixPM' => strtoupper($fix['FixPM'][$i]) === 'NULL' ? NULL : $fix['FixPM'][$i],`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to me to be a(n unreported?) bug in PDO's prepared statement emulation:

1. the [implementation](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#434) of `PDOStatement::execute()` [eventually](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#497) invokes [`pdo_parse_params()`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c#432);
2. that, in turn, [attempts to quote/escape values](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c#584) based on the relevant parameter's data type (as indicated by the `$data_type` arguments to [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)—all parameters provided as `$input_parameters` to [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`, as stated in the documentation of that function);
3. string-typed values are escaped/quoted by [calling](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c#604) the relevant database driver's [`quoter()`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h#302) method irrespective of whether they are `null`: in the case of PDO_MySQL, that's [`mysql_handle_quoter()`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#302), which (eventually) passes the value to either [`mysqlnd_cset_escape_quotes()`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_charset.c#686) or [`mysql_cset_escape_slashes()`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_charset.c#740), depending on the server's [`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) SQL mode;
4. given a `null` argument, both of those functions return an empty string.

My opinion is that, prior to [switching on the parameter's type](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c#584) (in step 2 above), `pdo_parse_params()` should set the type to `PDO::PARAM_NULL` if the value is `null`.  However, some might argue that this would prevent type-specific handling of `null` values where appropriate, in which case the [string case](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/php/ext/pdo/pdo_sql_parser.c#602) (in step 3 above) should definitely handle `null` values before proceeding with a call to the driver's `quoter()` method.

As an interim workaround, disabling prepared statement emulation is usually for the best anyway:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
```

Comment: nice. Very detailed and focused answer!