# "set names" vs mysqli_set_charset — besides affecting mysqli_escape_string, are they identical?

Tags: php, mysql, security, encoding, libmysql

It [seems to be   common knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650834/632951) to use [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) / [`mysqli::set_charset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) instead of the direct MySQL query [`set names`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html).

The reason often cited is that `set names` is insecure because the encoding used for [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) / [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) will only be set by a call to `mysql_set_charset` / `mysqli::set_charset`. (Another reason cited is that the PHP docs says it's "not recommended" [§](https://www.php.net/mysql_set_charset).)

However, is it safe to use the direct MySQL query `set names` if we use prepared statements andor [**other means of escaping**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/632951) besides `mysql_real_escape_string` / `mysqli::real_escape_string` /  [`mysqli_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php)?

Besides affecting the encoding of  `mysql_real_escape_string` / `mysqli::real_escape_string` / `mysqli_escape_string`, Is there any difference between `set names` vs `mysql_set_charset`/`mysqli::set_charset`?

Answer (score 6):

**Calling `SET NAMES` on the connection is equivalent to calling `set_charset`, provided you call neither `get_charset` nor `mysql_real_escape_string` (and friends).**

---

When you call `set_charset`, PHP does two things. First, it calls `SET NAMES` on the connection. Second, it remembers what charset you set. That state information is later used only in the `get_charset` and `mysql_real_escape_string` (and friends) functions. Therefore, if you don't use these functions, then you may consider the two equivalent.

Let's walk the source:

1. Userland functions `mysql_set_charset` and `mysqli_set_charset` call...
2. Engine function `mysql_set_character_set` calls...
3. Engine macro `mysqlnd_set_character_set`, which is defined as:

   `#define mysqlnd_set_character_set(conn, cs) \
       ((conn)->data)->m->set_charset((conn)->data, (cs)))`

   and expands to...
4. `MYSQLND_METHOD(mysqlnd_conn_data, set_charset)` which [contains](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_connection.c#L1193-L1207) the following code (numbered for discussion, these are not actual source line numbers):

---

```
 1   if (PASS == conn->m->local_tx_start(conn, this_func)) {
 2      char * query;
 3      size_t query_len = mnd_sprintf(&query, 0, "SET NAMES %s", csname);
 4 
 5      if (FAIL == (ret = conn->m->query(conn, query, query_len))) {
 6          php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Error executing query");
 7      } else if (conn->error_info->error_no) {
 8          ret = FAIL;
 9      } else {
10           conn->charset = charset;
11      }
12      mnd_sprintf_free(query);
13 
14      conn->m->local_tx_end(conn, this_func, ret);
15   }
```

---

As you can see, PHP calls `SET NAMES` on the connection itself (line 3). PHP also tracks the charset just set (line 10). The comments further discuss what happens with `conn->charset`, but suffice to say it winds up only being in `get_charset` and `mysql_real_escape_string` (and friends).

So, if you don't care about this state, and you agree to use neither `get_charset` nor `mysql_real_escape_string`, then you may call `SET NAMES` on the connection itself with no ill effect.

As an aside, and I've never done this, but it looks like compiling PHP with `-DPHP_DEBUG=1` will enable substantial debugging through various `DBG` macros. That may be useful in seeing how your code is passing through this block.

Comment: OK, now that PHP knows (`conn->charset = charset`) that the connection is in a given "charset", what will it later do with that info?

Comment: @RickJames Only two uses of the stored `charset` state: [`mysqli_get_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-charset.php) uses it for obvious parity and [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) uses it to know how many bytes per character for escaping purposes. Since the OP is managing safe quoting himself, and presumably knows the charset, the state value PHP tracks are irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that confirms my assertion that there are two _independent_ things going on -- escaping for building the SQL string, and transcoding the bytes from the client encoding to whatever the column/table's `CHARACTER SET` for storing.

Comment: But I am still puzzled as to why `mysqli_real_escape_string` would care how many "bytes per character" there are.  And what does that mean for variable-length encodings, such as utf8?

Comment: @RickJames There are two escapers: [one for quotes](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_charset.c#L729-L778) and [another for slashes](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_charset.c#L783-L858). The code tells all, but in a nutshell: checking for unicode allows for a copy optimization.

Comment: [This answer on how PDO uses `bindParam` and friends may also be interesting.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13942285/2908724)

Comment: It seems to depend on `mb_valid` and `mb_charlen`; do they look at the charset?

Comment: @RickJames [mb_valid](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_structs.h#L189) and [mb_charlen](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_structs.h#L188) are function pointers to [character set specific implementations](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_charset.c#L485) that validate and return character length, respectively. So these implementations are *de facto* character set aware.

Comment: And they are 'aware' only if you run `set_charset`?  And not if you simply do `SET NAMES`?  How will things break of one does only `SET NAMES`?

Comment: @RickJames Q1: Yes. Q2: Yes. Q3: If one does only `SET NAMES`, then one forfeits the ability to use `get_charset` and `mysql_real_escape_string` (and friends). Since the OP stipulated he was doing *neither* `get_charset` nor `mysql_real_escape_string` (and friends), then - in that case and that case alone - calling `SET NAMES` is equivalent to calling `set_charset`.

Answer (score 3):

Two things must be done (in this area):

- Escape quotation marks (and other characters) before putting them inside quotes.  Otherwise the quotes would give you syntax errors.
- Establish the *encoding* of the bytes in the client.  This is so that `INSERTs`/`SELECTs` will know how to change the bytes during the write/read.

The first needs to escape apostrophe and double-quote, since both of those are acceptable quote marks for strings in MySQL syntax.  Then, the escape character, itself, needs escaping.  Those 3 characters are sufficient for must applications.  However if you are trying to escape a `BLOB` (such as a .jpg), various control characters may cause trouble.  You are probably better off converting to hex, then using `UNHEX()`, to avoid issues.  Note:  Nothing is mentioned here about character sets.  If you aren't dealing with `BLOBs`, you can get away with PHP's `addslashes()`.

The second item's purpose is to say "this stream of bytes is encoded this way (utf8/latin1/etc)".  It's only use is for converting between the `CHARACTER SET` of the column being stored/fetched and the desired encoding in your client (PHP, etc).  It is handled in a variety of ways by various languages.  For PHP:

- `mysql_*` -- Do *not* use this interface; it is deprecated and will soon be removed.
- `mysqli_*` -- `mysqli::set_charset(...)`
- PDO -- `new PDO('...;charset=UTF8', ...)`

Does `set_charset()` do something with real_escape_string?  I do not know.  But it should not matter.  `SET NAMES` obviously cannot since it is a MySQL command, and knows nothing about PHP.

`htmlentities()` is another PHP function in this area.  It turns 8-bit codes into `&` entities.  This should not be used going *into* MySQL.  It would only mask other problems.  Use it only in certain situations involving HTML, not PHP or MySQL.

The only reasonable `CHARACTER SETs`to use today are ascii, latin1, utf8, and utf8mb4.  Those have no "characters" in the "control" area.  Sjis and a few other character sets do.  This confusion over control characters *may* be a reason for real_escape_string existing.

Conclusion:

As I see it, you need two mechanisms:  One for escaping, and one for establishing the encoding in the client.  They are separate.

If they are tied together, the PHP manual has failed to provide any compelling reason for picking one method over another.

Comment: bishop's answer is possibly more complete than mine.  His is certainly more 'researched'.

Answer (score 1):

mysql: the whole interface is deprecated, so don't use any of it at all (PHP 7 removes the interface).

mysqli (and PDO) has prepared statements that make the use of `real_escape_string` not needed (nor wanted). 
-> So if you use mysqli and prepared statements only: no worries how you set the charset.

Since you care about security: I see little point in not using prepared statements.

Once you use mysqli's prepared statements the only way forward is to use `$mysqli->set_charset()` as you can't simply concatenate multiple sql statements in one string anymore.

Hence the question to know the difference is at most academic and not relevant in real life.

In summary:

- mysql: don't use at all.
- mysqli: use prepared statements and hence the `set_charset()` method
  Also: you won't need real_escape_string anymore once you use prepared statements.
- or -of course- use PDO and it's methods.

Comment: It does not address the original question.

Comment: Prepared statements do not allow you to issue multiple sql statements in one string ... - so the ````$mysqli->set_charset()```` is the way to go no matter what.

Comment: The question was "Is there any difference between". Not sure how your answer and comment are relevant, sorry. I do not say what you said is wrong (since it is not), I'm just saying it's not what OP asked.

Comment: Tried to explain in the answer why the difference is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, I don't agree that the difference is irrelevant. Irregardless of what one *should* do, the question *why* still makes sense.

Comment: `SET NAMES` and `set_charset` tell the server what encoding the bytes are in.  "Binding" does not know or care how the strings are encoded.  So it is _not_ sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`SET NAMES ...` is a convenience alias:

> A `SET NAMES 'charset_name'` statement is equivalent to these three
>   statements:
>
> ```
> SET character_set_client = charset_name;
> SET character_set_results = charset_name;
> SET character_set_connection = charset_name;
> ```
>
> Setting character_set_connection to charset_name also implicitly sets
>   collation_connection to the default collation for `charset_name`.

... that provides MySQL Server with all the [text-encoding information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) required for current connection. So far so good.

But PHP is also involved and it will not learn anything from here because it's basically a random user query. There are two things that PHP will not do for obvious performance reasons:

- Scan all user queries sent to the server to detect calls to SET NAMES.
- Ask MySQL for current values of the involved directives every time something needs to be done.

In short: this method notifies the server but not the client. However, dedicated PHP functions do both things.

Comment: Then comes the question of _why_ PHP needs to know or care about the encoding.