# UTF-8 Insert Query With MYSQL not working on Deployment server

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I created an application whith UTF-8 database charset. When creating connection using php I am executing `mysqli_query($link, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8')`.

It was working fine on **localhost** with both `SELECT`, `INSERT` etc. I deployed the application on web with some sample data and quickly browsed the page I saw **UTF-8** characters nicely.

The next day client called me data is showing like `??????` when I add some record through provided interface **I was surprised he was right** but On localhost it was working fine.

After some searching I found multiple answers like execute these queries

- `set character_set_client='utf8'`
- `set character_set_results='utf8'`
- `set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'`
- `SET NAMES 'utf8'`
- and setting then encoding in response etc

**None of them worked** but this `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')` one.

My Question is

1. Why It was working on localhost, and only `INSERT or UPDATE` Query was creating problem after deployment but `SELECT` was working fine
2. What is the difference between `mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8')` and `mysqli_query($link, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8')`

Comment: Please read [this excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/3536236)

Comment: Another [_excellent answer_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596294/set-names-vs-mysqli-set-charset-besides-affecting-mysqli-escape-string-are/37947771#37947771)

Comment: [_This_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) says that "question marks" arise from failure to have utf8 text and `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Comment: What characters turned into question marks?  There is still the question of utf8 vs utf8mb4.

Answer (score 0):

Your localhost database might have been set up with utf8 collation but the remote web server's one was set up incorrectly.

An alternative to localhost based development is using a vagrant virtual machine. You can set this up as closely to production as possible.

`mysqli_set_charset` does more than set the client character set. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php which was linked to from the manual page for `mysqli_set_charset`

Comment: i checked both were with `utf8`

Comment: I have yet to discover a character for which `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')` matters.