# use of NULL as a condition in PHP PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

here is a parameterized query:

```
SELECT
field1,field2,etc1,etc2
FROM my_table WHERE
conditionA=:conditionA AND
conditionB=:conditionB
```

and my parameters:

```
array( 'conditionA'=> 5, 'conditionB'=>NULL )
```

Now in this theoretical case, `conditionB` could be a value OR it could be null.  But in SQL, you do not say `conditionB=NULL` - you write it "`conditionB IS NULL`".

How am I supposed to do this?  First of all, if I pass `'conditionB'=>NULL` in my params, then I'm assuming that node is simply not passed.  Second, am I going to need to rewrite the query between "=" and "IS" based on the type value of `conditionB`, or can PDO do this for me as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql handles `NULL` differently and you [cannot use common comparison operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) and even [`STRCMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) [doesn't do what you need](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/40709/0).

When I needed to implement `a != b` on strings I've end up using `(a IS NULL XOR b IS NULL) OR (a != b)`...

So I think you can either [implement 2 different queries based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14078807/1149736) 
or extend your condition to

```
WHERE conditionA=:conditionA
AND (
    (conditionB IS NULL AND :conditionB IS NULL) OR (conditionB=:conditionB)
)
```

Comment: that's the best answer, but I must say I see this as a shortcoming of PDO to make things easier.  This is  a fairly common occurrence I think

Comment: @SamuelFullman I think this is thing of MySQL... You may write boolean function yourself to compare items correctly without having to write all the xors, ors, ands, isnulls and stuff... But I think indexes won't work on that ... MySQL sucks with nulls :-/

Comment: The entire `(
    (conditionB IS NULL AND :conditionB IS NULL) OR (conditionB=:conditionB)
)` segment can be shortened down to `conditionB <=> :conditionB`.