# Execute PDO with an array containing null values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, null

I need to update a database and I use PDO's `execute()` method by giving it an array as parameters.

The idea is that it gives me an error when trying to insert a `NULL` value...

Here's an example of query/parameters sent:

Generated query:

```
UPDATE table SET name=?, id_extra1=?, id_extra2=? WHERE id_something=?
```

Array of parameters:

```
array (size=8)
  'name' => string 'testing' (length=6)
  'id_extra1' => string '2' (length=1)
  'id_extra2' => null
  'id_something' => string '1958' (length=4)
```

So the `NULL` value is for `id_extra2`

In the code for `id_extra2` I have a condition like this *(the idea is that I have either an ID or 0 and then I have to update the DB value with `NULL`)*:

```
if ($_POST['id_extra2']==0) {
    $_POST['id_extra2'] = null;
}
```

I tried setting `$_POST['id_extra2']` to `''` and to `NULL` and to `'null'` but it's still not working.

Comment: **what** error it is giving you?

Comment: @eggyal I cannot use bindValue, I need to add the parameters list as an array in the `execute()` method

Comment: Just set to to empty string, i.e `''`

Comment: @YourCommonSense - it simply returns `false` (it's the result of the `execute()` method)... I ran the generated query in a SQL editor and it's working just fine. So the issue here is with the NULL parameter sent as a param to the `execute()` method.

Comment: @Simon_eQ - as I specified, I already tried this... still no luck! :(

Comment: when you have an array, why can't you iterate over it via foreach and use bindValue, why do you **have to** pass the array as a whole to the execute method? EDIT: Because, as it says here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php " All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR".

Comment: I am sure, you can use some function to get take that one array, from the POST/GET global you are working on.

Comment: is there a constraint on your table field so that it doesn't allow empty values in that field

Comment: @DevZer0 It's not a constraint in the database.

Comment: @stef77 - I use it this way because I have some dynamically generated queries and bindParams in loops aren't working so great. Already tried this once and it gave me some headaches

Comment: Are you using [emulated prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.attr-emulate-prepares)?  If so, PHP places quotes around each parameter when inlining as string literals into the SQL (per @stef77's comment above), so `NULL` values are impossible.  If you use native prepared statements, this ought to work.  Please confirm?

Comment: @eggyal I'm not using anything, I'm just passing my array to the `execute()` method like this : `execute($params)`... It's working great, except for this case! The big wonderful NULL

Comment: @cristic84 Please have a look at my answer, since it doesn't seem possible to get NULL working with directly passing it to execute. So, you might want to consider a workaround like I provided (or something similar). Should mean little to no more work compared to directly using execute.

Comment: @cristic84: You're using prepared statements.  By default, PDO just *emulates* real statement preparation by escaping your parameters and then inlining them into the SQL for transmission to the MySQL server; alternatively (and IMV preferably) you can use "native" prepared statements whereby the statement is first prepared on the MySQL server, and parameters then transmitted separately.  `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`.

Comment: @eggyal - tried what you've suggested me and still nothing

Comment: @eggyal would you please remove the link which is rather misleading?

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using bindValue instead of passing the array to execute. As it says [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.

It should be possible to make this pretty transparent to the rest of your application, since you already have the values you want to UPDATE as an array. Try e.g. something like this:

```
<?php
function executeWithDataTypes(PDOStatement $sth, array $values) {
    $count = 1;
    foreach($values as $value) {
        $sth->bindValue($count, $values['value'], $values['type']);
        $count++;
    }

    return $sth->execute();
}

$sth = $handle->prepare("UPDATE table SET name = ?, id_extra1 = ?, id_extra2 = ? WHERE id_something = ?");

$values = array();
$values[] = array('value' => 'testing', 'type' => PDO::PARAM_STR);
$values[] = array('value' => 2, 'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT);
$values[] = array('value' => null, 'type' => PDO::PARAM_NULL);
$values[] = array('value' => 1958, 'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT);

$result = executeWithDataTypes($sth, $values);
?>
```

As you noted that using bindParam gave you headaches in the past, please be aware of the subtle difference between [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). Personally, I never use bindParam because of side effects which make it harder to understand scripts, though there are of course cases where these effects will come in handy.

EDIT: You could of course simplify the function even more and get rid of the need of specifying the type as additional key in the passed array by doing something like:

```
$type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
switch(true) {
    case is_null($value): $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL; break;
    case is_numeric($value): $type = PDO::PARAM_INT; break;
    // ...
    default: break;
}
```

and determine the type based on the type of the value passed in the array; however, that's more error-prone, since e.g. floats are also numeric and that would lead to a wrong decision in the above switch statement, but I thought I'd mention it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: I'm currently adding another update method that implements what you suggested me... I'll be back with an answer. Thanks @stef77

Comment: Here's what I did. When I have "normal" values it works flawless! If I have the `NULL` case, it returns FALSE :(... Any idea? http://pastebin.com/Tad8yFU8

Comment: What is displayed if you call `print_r($updatQuery->errorInfo());` in case of failure?

Comment: Besides, be aware of some issues in your pastebin script: you won't be able to insert a string called "null" (better: set it to really `null`, not `"null"`, and check for `is_null`), the string "23" is not `is_int` and will therefore be passed with PDO::PARAM_STR and probably some more issues. And I don't understand your utf8_decode, perhaps you should change the collation of your database table to utf8_unicode_ci, the PDO connection to utf8 and your pages to utf8, so there's no special characters lost.

Comment: here's the error ==> `[2] => Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` - I have a constraint (key), but I also allow `NULL` values. As I said, I tested the code in an SQL editor and it runs perfectly with the `NULL` value... As for the `=='null'` verification, I want it this way because I'll set the returned value as `'null'` myself, so it's not an issue (I will modify this later, for now I want to see it's working).

Comment: Also, the log shows me that the values are sent OK (especially the null one), so the bind type is ok.

Comment: Let's get rid of all the fancy functions and wrappings and go back to the basics. Please do a `$updateQuery->bindValue(3, null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);` and the other parameters accordingly. If this works, you're good, if not, please provide details of your table definition statements including constraints, especially ON UPDATE clauses. You might also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo as already mentioned in another comment.

Comment: I'm having the same `constraint` problem when binding `null` value inside an array. If it helps, I found that when setting an array value to `null`, `print_r($array)` will show `Array( [0] => 'value' [1] => [2] => 'other value' )`. Key #1 is the null value, so we see the value is not set to "null", is actually nulled out, so there's no way any SQL NULL value will be set. Maybe it cannot be done with array binding.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such question.

### JUST send your null value into the database

No special function, not a complex over-engineered solution is ever needed.

It just works. Any method - `execute()`, `bindValue()` or `bindParam()` - use either method you wish. All you need is just a `null` value. And then *just use* it in the query as any other value.

```
$null = null;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute([$null]);

$stmt->bindParam(1, $null);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bindValue(1, $null);
$stmt->execute();
```

### All work

Comment: it has 7k views which means people are coming here looking for a way to add a null value. though a closure wouldn't change anything so be it