# NULL in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have the following prepared statement.  All is good...

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare('UPDATE t1 SET c1=? WHERE c2=? AND c3!=?');
$stmt->execute(array(1,2,3));
```

But now I wish to use the same prepared statement, but include NULL values in the WHERE clause.

```
$stmt->execute(array(1,NULL,NULL));
```

Will this resolve to `UPDATE t1 SET c1=1 WHERE c2=NULL AND c3!=NULL`?  Isn't the proper query `UPDATE t1 SET c1=1 WHERE c2 IS NULL AND c3 IS NOT NULL`?  How can I have a single prepared statement which allows both NULL and not NULL values in the WHERE clause?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute PDO with an array containing null values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723839/execute-pdo-with-an-array-containing-null-values)

Comment: @RahilWazir  Referenced "possible duplicate" is for inserting NULL.  INSERTs or SETs do not cause a problem, only the WHERE clause.

Comment: To the individual who downvoted.  Please give reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked if a SQL query containing

```
 WHERE col = ?
```

will automatically be converted to

```
 WHERE col IS NULL
```

by binding a NULL value to the parameter.

The answer is **no**.  If a column has a NULL value, it can never compare equal to anything.

You need a different prepared query for that.

Comment: Thanks Ollie.  Do I understand you in that I cannot use the same prepared statement when having NULL and non-NULL in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Correct. If you think NULL might come into play, you need to handle that in your query, which is why nullable columns shouldn't be overused.

Comment: Thanks again Ollie.  Well, that is a bummer!