# bindParam and NULL int values

Tags: php, mysql

I am using bindParam to set values for a MySQL insert. The column in question is an INT (11). It has a default of NULL and null is allowed. However, using bindParam it always receives a 0. I have confirmed that my $_POST['value'] is indeed null.

```
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (:column)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':column',$_POST['value'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

It keeps inserting a '0' instead of NULL if the POST value was ''.

Comment: Have you matched value and type (`===`)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1391801/658086

Comment: `column` is a reserved word in mysql -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Darren good call.. it was not coming as NULL but as '', so I said if is '' set to NULL and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be matching the complete case (*Answer and type*) with `===` ([<sup>*Read More*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php))

Which most likely means that your value is **not** `null` like you presume it is.

Ensure it is by checking (*pseudo code below*):

```
if(VALUE !=== NULL) {
   value = null
}
```

But you get the idea there? If not just comment :-)

---

And as [**`aldanux`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856172/bindparam-and-null-int-values/24856242#comment38599328_24856172) mentioned in his comment, you have to wrap the column in backticks as it is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html):

```
INSERT INTO table (`column`) VALUES (:column)
```

Comment: Yes sorry was just for the example.

Comment: `!===` ??? Maybe you meant `!=============`?  How super, duper strict should the comparison be?