# 'PDOException': Invalid parameter number with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

Tags: php, sql, pdo

My issue is I'm trying to connect to my database (it has 4 elements to it, ID, Date, Time and Last Value(last_value)) but as I'm intending to put my data into the database the "message_id" element is null. Can anyone help me out?

**Stack Trace**

> 'PDOException': Invalid parameter number with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: number of bound variables does not match number of
>   tokens' in
>   C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_framework\class.CourseWorkDatabaseWrapper.php:78
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_framework\class.CourseWorkDatabaseWrapper.php(78):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_download_message_data\class.CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataModel.php(216):
>   CourseWorkDatabaseWrapper->safe_query('SELECT message_...', Array) #2
>   C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_download_message_data\class.CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataModel.php(169):
>   CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataModel->do_check_if_data_exists() #3
>   C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_framework\class.CourseWorkContainer.php(126):
>   CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataModel->do_store_downloaded_message_data() #4 C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_download_message_data\class.CourseWorkDownloadMessageDataController.php(6):
>   CourseWorkCont in
>   C:\wamp\www\CTEC3110\includes\classes\cw_framework\class.CourseWorkDatabaseWrapper.php
>   on line 91

**Check if Data Exists code**

```
$m_message_id = NULL;
$m_message_date = $this->c_arr_download_message_data['message-date'];
$m_message_time = $this->c_arr_download_message_data['message-time'];
$m_message_last_value = $this->c_arr_download_message_data['message-data'];

$m_sql_query_string = CourseWorkSqlQuery::does_message_exist();

$m_arr_sql_query_parameters =
array(  ':message_id' => $m_message_id,
        ':message_date' => $m_message_date,
        ':message_time' => $m_message_time,
        ':message_last_value' => $m_message_last_value);

$this->c_obj_database_handle->safe_query($m_sql_query_string, $m_arr_sql_query_parameters);
```

**SQL Query**

```
public static function does_message_exist()
{
    $m_sql_query_string  = "SELECT message_id, message_time, message_date, message_last_value ";
    $m_sql_query_string .= "FROM cw_messages ";
    $m_sql_query_string .= "WHERE message_id = :message_id ";
    $m_sql_query_string .= "AND message_time = :message_time ";
    $m_sql_query_string .= "AND message_date = :message_date ";
    $m_sql_query_string .= "AND message_last_value = :message_last_value ";
    $m_sql_query_string .= "LIMIT 1";
    return $m_sql_query_string;
}
```

**Query Checking Code (Under a try/catch)**

```
$m_temp = array();
$this->c_obj_database_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$this->c_obj_stmt = $this->c_obj_database_handle->prepare($m_query_string);

// bind the parameters
if (sizeof($m_arr_query_parameters) > 0)
{
    foreach ($m_arr_query_parameters as $m_param_key => $m_param_value)
    {
        $m_temp[$m_param_key] = $m_param_value;
        $this->c_obj_stmt->bindParam($m_param_key+1, $m_temp[$m_param_key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}

// execute the query
$m_execute_result = $this->c_obj_stmt->execute();
$this->c_arr_database_connection_messages['execute-OK'] = $m_execute_result;
$m_database_query_execute_error = false;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I insert NULL values using PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo)

Comment: @hjpotter92 Not relevant, sorry. It's not that I'm trying to insert the null value using PDO; it's that I'm trying to test the data I've got against pre-existing values already in my database.

Comment: @meda He suggested that this was a possible duplicate of another question, but I'll try it anyway and get back to this.

EDIT: No luck. Even using your recommendation still returns the same error and stack trace.

    $this->c_obj_stmt->bindValue($m_param_key+1, $m_param_value, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: @Raisus see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, since you are using named parameter, it does not makes sense to increment the key by 1:

```
foreach ($m_arr_query_parameters as $m_param_key => $m_param_value)
{
    $this->c_obj_stmt->bindValue($m_param_key, $m_param_value);
}
```