# Cannot set NULL with PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

I know there are other posts on this topic but they don't answer the basic question. The previous answers all say to use PDO::PARAM_NULL but doesn't that remove the entire reason for using PDO anyway?

Here is my code:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users_address (uid,street1,street2,city,state,region,postalcode,country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $street1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $street2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $state, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $region, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $postalcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(8, $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Not all of these values are required so sometimes they are null. Both varchar and int database fields have default=null. How can I prepare this so that if a variable happens to be null, the null gets inserted? All of the other answers I have seen pass NULL for the second parameter but how do I know at run time it is a null?

To be really clear. I do not want to implicitly insert a null. I want to insert a variable which MAY be a null if the user did not complete the form. Not all fields are required on the form. For example, in this example, $street2.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to insert (i.e., what do `$street1`, `$city`... contain?) and what do you get instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I insert NULL values using PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo)

Comment: Not a duplicate Dan and I explained why. :) 

The fields are coming from a form that was posted. Not all fields are required so some may be null. I get an error saying cannot process nulls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL, or at least standard SQL and most SQL flavours —yeah, I'm looking at you, Oracle— `NULL` is a special value that is completely different from empty strings. In SQL code you use the `NULL` keyword to represent the former and empty quotes for the latter.

Your input comes from HTML forms. HTML forms are always submitted as plain text: you don't have anything else, no numbers, no dates... and of course no nulls. Whenever you need an actual `NULL`, you need some post-processing. Happily, PDO will convert PHP nulls to SQL nulls:

```
$stmt->bindValue(6, $region!='' ? $region : null, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

PDO (and SQL) are just unaware of HTML and won't do it for you.

I've also replaced your `bindParam()` with `bindValue()` to make it all less verbose.

Comment: I did this and even set $mynull = null and passed it as $mynull, but get this warning:

"Only variables should be passed by reference."

it is only a warning, but I'd prefer cleaner code with no warnings. Do I need to do all the assignments outside the bind?

Comment: Yes, you are using bindParam() so you need to pass an actual variable. Perhaps you just want to use bindValue().

Answer (score 2):

Use `PARAM_NULL` to insert a `null` value or the other params you already have:

```
if (!isset($uid) || strlen($uid) == 0) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
} else {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

Comment: Could I just use a ternary operator on the variable line? I suppose that would work.

$stmt->bindParam(1, ($uid) ? $uid : null, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: I think that should work. I've read that `PARAM_INT` with null works.

Comment: Why don't you insert an empty string instead of null when no information is given?

Comment: Because empty strings are not allowed in integers and I don't want a 0.

Comment: Ok that's right :D When I read your question I thought you can't pass `null` to `PARAM_STR` but you should be able to, like Alvaro answered.