# INSERT NULL into sql query using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$var1 = NULL;
$var2 = NULL;
$var3 = NULL;
$var4 = NULL;

/*  (...) code for logical flow condition (...) */

/* After the code, only var1 is different
 */

// $var1 = "something"

$query = "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ('$var1','$var2','$var3','$var4');
```

Here is the deal:
All fields for all vars are **unique**. The problem with the code is that the database doesn't insert with "duplicate value for $var2,3,4" because it is inserting the vars as ' ' instead of NULL. I want the values to be NULL **BUT** mantain it all in a coherent query... in a kind of concatenation if you may say, as to not disrupt the easiness of my logical flow code...

I want

```
$query = "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ('$var1','$var2','$var3','$var4');
```

To be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ('$var1',NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

instead of how it is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ('$var1','','','');
```

So, how can I do this **keeping the variables** in the query, both when NULL and not NULL? Tyvm for your help

Comment: You could override [`to_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method.

Comment: Investigate the usage of PDO, that will help you build your query http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo

Comment: @Scuzzy Using mysqli...

Comment: @vee this is an EXCELLENT idea. I don't know how I didn't think it sooner...

Comment: if you don't pass any value in insert query ,by default php insert null in database (if you allow the filed can be null )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test whether the value is a string or null, and only add quotes in the SQL if it's a string:

```
$var1_sql = $var1 === null ? "NULL" : "'$var1'";
$var2_sql = $var2 === null ? "NULL" : "'$var2'";
$var3_sql = $var3 === null ? "NULL" : "'$var3'";
$var4_sql = $var4 === null ? "NULL" : "'$var4'";

$query = "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ($var1_sql, $var2_sql, $var3_sql, $var4_sql)";
```

But it would be better to use a prepared query.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: ty, you answer pointed me towards the right direction. I just changed `$var=NULL` to `$var="NULL"` and it worked

Comment: But when the variable contains something other than `NULL` you have to remember to add the extra quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$var1 = NULL;
$var2 = "'a value'";
$var3 = NULL;
$var4 = "'another val'";

$query = "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4)";
```

Comment: This made the query like this `VALUES (,,,,)` ... (when all vars are null)