# MySQL: What happens when something is equal with NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null

I have a `CASE WHEN` function in my query. Something like this:

```
CASE WHEN h.user_id = :user_id THEN '1' 
     ELSE '0'
END paid
```

And I pass `:user_id` like this:

```
$sth->bindValue(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

---

Well, Sometimes `$user_id` is `NULL`. Already I heard when something is equal with `NULL` in the query, something bad will happen. Now I want to know, what happens when `$user_id` is `NULL`?

I tested it, but all fine, I don't see any problem. When `$user_id` is `NULL`, `$result['paid']` is `1` or that `CASE..WHEN` breaks?

---

**EDIT:**

All I want to do it, when `h.user_id = :user_id` then `paid = 1`. But sometimes `:user_id` is `null`. How can I escape `null` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is because, according to the standard, comparing anything to **`null`** gives a result of **`null`**, which eventually gets coerced to **`false`**. Thus your expression, as written, will always return `0` when either `:user_id` or `h.user_id` is **`null`**.

Fortunately, this situation arises often enough that MySQL provides a bit of syntactic sugar called the ["spaceship" or "`NULL`-safe equal" operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), which looks like `<=>`. It is used exactly like the normal `=` operator, except that it returns **`false`** (not **`null`**) when comparing a **`null`** to a non-**`null`**, and **`true`** when comparing two **`null`**.

The expression then becomes

```
CASE WHEN h.user_id <=> :user_id THEN '1' 
     ELSE '0'
END paid
```

Answer (score 1):

If the passed parameter is truly a null value, then the result of the case expression should be 0 because null will not be equal with any of the field values, so the else branch have to kick in. There is no need to escape null values.

In order to appropriately pass null value from php to mysql using PDO see [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo)