# NULL in MySQL PDO WHERE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, null

`$id` can but is not necessarily `NULL`.  Other than using PHP to test `$id` for `NULL`, and changing the query to `IS NULL`, how can this query be performed?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute([$id]);
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1391801/1032531, I tried `bindValue(':id', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);`, but get error `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`

I've also tried `$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_NULL);`, and while no error, I get no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the ANSI standard `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator.  This returns true for `NULL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL`.

MySQL supports this using the `<=>` comparison operator.  So you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE id <=> ?
```

This assumes that you actually want `NULL` values for `id` when you compare to `NULL`.  Often, the desired logic is to take all rows if the parameter is `NULL`:

```
WHERE id = ? OR (? IS NULL)
```

or:

```
WHERE id = COALESCE(?, id)
```

Comment: Would this not return all records if `$id` is `NULL`?  If `$id` is `NULL`, I only which to return records where `id` is `NULL`.

Comment: Ah, I see how `<=>` works now.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to. Thanks!  Is it a MySQL only operator?

Comment: @user1032531 . . . Probably.  Given that the ANSI standard is `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`, then other databases would support the standard version.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, `null`s in SQL aren't values, and can't be evaluated with the `=` operator, but have to be specifically addressed with the `is` operator. One neat way of doing this in one shot is to use two conditions at once, one handling the `null`s and one handling the real values:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE id=? OR (id IS NULL AND ? IS NULL");
$stmt->execute([$id, $id]);
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thans Mureinik,  I wouldn't have thought of that.  I am messing around with `bindParam()`.  Do you know whether it will also work?

Comment: @user1032531 `bindParam()` is a longer way of doing the same thing, essentially (and more powerful one, at that, as it lets you specify the type of variable). The same technique should work there too.

Comment: Do you know how `bindParam()` would be used?  I am trying it but getting the same results as just passing an array using `?` or `:id`.