# PDO integer nullable value issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-5.6

I have a code block like this ;

```
$a='';

$Query =$db->prepare("UPDATE TblUsers
SET Age = :age
WHERE
 IsActive=1 ")
$Query->bindParam(":age",$a,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$Query->execute();
```

When i run this code i get this error ;

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for
>   column 'Age' at row 1'

But it will be nullable variable when i add '' . but i get this error. Where is my fail ?

Comment: post the schema and the value for the intended value for `$a`. Right now, there's no value for it. Or, allow empty/NULL values.

Comment: If you want the value of `age` to be null sometines then you have to set it to `null` instead of  `''`

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The String of age is empty and the query expects a value int

Comment: I Want to change empty string to null variable. How can i do it with PDO ? There is any option it or i need write a function about it ?

Comment: @ZibianDomichi  you need to make column `default-value` `null` in your db table

Comment: @AlivetoDie its null sir.

Comment: @AlivetoDie its working but i dont want it . I want to solve it with pdo.

Comment: ALTER your table instead and as [per my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796027/pdo-integer-nullable-value-issue#comment78549559_45796027). *"I want to solve it with pdo"* - why do you feel the need to do this with PDO?

Comment: Mayde there is any option about it Like
$db->options(PDO::ATTR_NULLINTEGER);

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo/18989269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `bindValue` like below:-

```
$Query =$db->prepare("UPDATE TblUsers
SET Age = :age
WHERE
 IsActive=1 ")
$Query->bindValue(':age', $a, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$Query->execute();
```

`bindParam` takes a variable, to reference, and doesn't pull in a value at the time of calling `bindParam`.

Referecne:-[How do I insert NULL values using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1391801/4248328)