# PHP PDO Prepared statement bind NULL value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to run a SQL query as a prepared statement - and I try to bind a `NULL` value. Well I've done some research on the web and yes, I already found all the known topics here on stackoverflow.

My code so far:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT c.*, COUNT(d.servername) as servercount, d.controller FROM customers C JOIN customerdata d ON c.id = d.customer WHERE isVdi = :isVdi AND d.controller = :controller GROUP BY d.customer ORDER BY c.name ASC, c.environment ASC");
            $stmt->bindValue(':isVdi', $isVdi);
            $stmt->bindValue(':controller', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But this doesn't work. I get an empty result array. When I replace the `controller = :controller` by `controller IS NULL` it works perfectly.

At the end, I would like to bind the param on :controller from a variable, but right now I'm trying to directly write the NULL into it, since that doesn't even work.

I found this way here:
[How do I insert NULL values using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo)

I also already tried with `PDO::PARAM_NULL` and all that stuff - nothing works. I really don't get it.

Thankful for any help.

Comment: am not quite sure about this, but the uppercase "C" here `FROM customers C` and using a lowercase "c" afterwards could be an issue. On a \*NIX OS, it is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Syscall OP already tried that as stated in the question

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner While I agree that this isn't really good, its 100 % not the problem. I changed it now, it still doesn't work. Btw: The query worked before I added the `AND d.controller = :controller` part - so that was no issue at all.

Comment: that's why I posted that as a comment ;-) @Twinfriends which I edited for future readers.

Comment: Just wondering if you're using PDO's error handling on the query. https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - That may have shot something out. Gordon's answer makes a lot of sense though, give that a shot.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah I'm using PDO's error handling. I write every error to some logfiles, but that query didn't gave me any error nor a warning. It just returned an empty array. Also Gordon's answer worked like a charm.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it :-) @Twinfriends

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(d.servername) as servercount, d.controller
FROM customers C JOIN
     customerdata d
     ON c.id = d.customer
WHERE isVdi = :isVdi AND d.controller = :controller
GROUP BY d.customer
ORDER BY c.name ASC, c.environment ASC;
```

Unfortunately, anything `= NULL` is never going to return true.  Even more unfortunately, MySQL does not support the ANSI standard `NULL`-safe comparator `is not distinct from`.  But happily it has an alternative.  You can try this:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(d.servername) as servercount, d.controller
FROM customers C JOIN
     customerdata d
     ON c.id = d.customer
WHERE isVdi = :isVdi AND
      d.controller <=> :controller
GROUP BY d.customer
ORDER BY c.name ASC, c.environment ASC;
```

Comment: That worked, I'll accept it in a few minutes. I'm kinda confused about that syntax, but I'll take it anyway. Thats what I thought, doing somehint `= NULL` is not good syntax for SQL, but I didn't see another way.

Comment: @Twinfriends . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference ;)