# PHP PDO mysql query to work with both column = '$var' and column IS NULL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a quite long mysql query, selecting data according to status field. I'm calling it for different statuses and it works well, but I have a scenario when I should get all records where status is null ONLY. Is there a way to do this without having to write 2 different sql queries?

Looks like I can't insert 'IS NULL' or '=' without it being rendered as a string.

I want to achieve this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, surname FROM ...
       ...             
       WHERE status ?;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($status === 'undefined' ? 'IS NULL' : " = '$status'"));
```

---

After all, here's what I did:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, surname FROM ...
       ...             
       WHERE status <=> ?;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($status === 'unfinished' ? null : $status));
```

Comment: look at this answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48644040/915467

Comment: a spaceship in the query and `$stmt->execute([$status === 'undefined' ? NULL : $status]);`

Answer (score -1):

Using parameterised queries, as indicated, is a safer way of introducing user input into your SQL statements.  However, it has the effect of treating all input as a parameter, and therefore will surroung any string literals with quotes - giving rise to the problem you have.

To deal with this issue, why not just modify the logic of the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, surname FROM ...
       ...             
       WHERE status";

if ($status === 'undefined') {
    $sql .= " IS NULL";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $sql .= " = ?"
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($status));
}
```

**Edit**

Updated to move the execution into the relevant part of the `if` statement becuase the parameters must not be specified if there is no placeholder in the SQL statement.