# Inserting date in null

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting date. It works when date is set, otherwise, it doesn't work.

DateBirth type is date and its default value is NULL.

Here is my php

```
$date_birth = isset($_POST['date_birth']) ? $_POST['date_birth'] : NULL;
```

Here is mysql

```
$adding_birth = "INSERT INTO person (DateBirth) VALUES ('$date_birth')";
```

How can I get date field in null?

Comment: Check in your database if `DateBirth` is `NOT NULL`

Comment: I have set it is NULL

Comment: `'$date_birth'` would mean the string `'NULL'`, by the way which your `DATETIME` field would not accept

Comment: i think you have set your `DateBirth` column as `NOT NULL` in your database.

Comment: default value is set in null and date type is date

Comment: use prepared statements this helps against and also with NULL values see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently adding NULL as an STRING to your database.
You have to rewrite your SQL command to:

```
$date_birth = isset($_POST['date_birth']) ? "'" . $_POST['date_birth'] . "'" : 'NULL';
$adding_birth = "INSERT INTO person (DateBirth) VALUES ($date_birth)";
```

When you do an echo in front of the SQL you will get, with the NULL in your case:

```
$adding_birth = "INSERT INTO person (DateBirth) VALUES ('NULL')";
```

And correct is:

```
$adding_birth = "INSERT INTO person (DateBirth) VALUES (NULL)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `NULL` as string:

```php
$date_birth = isset($_POST['date_birth']) ? $_POST['date_birth'] : 'NULL';
```

when PHP replaces variable in a query string - `$date_birth` is replaced by empty string, while you need a string NULL

Comment: Have you tried this code yourself?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I have tried this code but I get incorrect date value message.

Comment: @ewef Yes the question was for Distdev

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava cuz you close this question